# Пропадают числа в начале строки при печати

Tags: ms-word

Началось всё с того, что неизвестно откуда прибывший .docx вместо (в начале строки):

> 22.10.2020 р.

напечатал:

> .2020 р.

Причем на предпросмотре всё нормально, а при печати на любой принтер, включая печать в pdf - нет.
Но с некоторых пк на те же принтера печатается корректно.
Все пк Windows 10 v2004 и Microsoft Office 16.
Переустановка всего Microsoft Office не помогает.
Можно только локально, заметив проблему при печати файла, пересохранить его в .doc

Сейчас создал копию, думал поэкспериментировать, понять принцип, но..
Если удалить " р." в конце - дата перестаёт печататься вовсе. И (!!!) cntrl+z уже не возвращает положение дел на место.. Это окончательно сбило с толку.

Подобное уже когда-то было и с другим файлом - тогда просто вставил белую букву перед числом и забыл.

Проверил настройки вордовские настройки на пк, где проблема есть и где нет - настройки идентичны.

вот тут разобрана эта проблема, с тем отличием, что там проблема воспроизводится на всех пк https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E/b53b5b2d-9e94-4863-a8de-d24679bbbc50

Полная переустановка системы не помогла.